# What Telemetry Channel I should use? InMemoryChannel or ServerTelemetryChannel?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, telemetry

So I am creating webjob which will be processed in background of the webapp. I have configured my webjobs with InMemoryChannel because I thought there will be no power-cut issue or issues like latency in memory on App Service. In ServerTelemetryChannel it will store data on disk, which in this case is not possible when hosted on App Service. Am I thinking it right way? Should I continue using InMemoryChannel for production as well when the program is used as a webjob?

Right now with InMemoryChannel I am receiving logs properly with a bit delay on Application Insight when I am running console application on my machine and not on webjob.

Comment: ServerTelemetryChannel is more advanced compared with InMemoryChannel for reliable delivery, but it also makes only a best-effort attempt to send telemetry.

Comment: Can you suggest me any good practice to apply ServerTelemetryChannel  in my project. As I said I will use this console app as webjob so no there will be no disk